# Mongoose gte date object wont find record

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a Mongo-DB with one record, the following:

```
{
    "_id": "608c0f5ceee3254fcb0f9d1f",
    "outDated": false,
    "domain": "test.com",
    "releaseDate": "Tue May 04 2021 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)",
    "__v": 0
}
```

My Node.js-code looks like this:

```
getDomainsFromTodaysDate: async () => {

    await module.exports.connectToDb();

    return Domains.find({ 
      releaseDate: { $gte: new Date(dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')) }
    })
    .then(res => {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(`getDomainsFromTodaysDate error: ${error}`);
    });
  }
```

The dayjs-function output is:

```
const test = new Date(dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
console.log(test) // 2021-04-30T14:30:11.000Z
console.log(typeof test) // object
```

Mongoose-debug gives me this:

```
Mongoose: domains.find({ releaseDate: { '$gte': 'Fri Apr 30 2021 16:06:06 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)' }}, { projection: {} })
```

Still I dont get the record stated above from the DB. What am I doing wrong? Without the releaseDate-filter I receive the record.

Edit:
Here is part of the Schema where releaseDate appears:

```
return new mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: String,
    outDated: Boolean,
    domain: String,
    releaseDate: Date
});
```

From Robo3t:
[image: from Robo3t]

Comment: Can you show your schema & model? I think your date is stored as a string in DB. It needs to be stored as type `Date` for the `$gte` query to work

Comment: Thanks for answer. Updated original post with part of the Schema where "releaseDate" is represented.

Comment: Your schema and query look fine. Are you sure you get a result when you leave out the releaseDate query? You have an awkward combination of async, promise and return that probably won't return anything. You can also just use `new Date()` rather than `dayjs...`.

Comment: Tried with only releaseDate: { $gte: new Date() } but still the same result. Leaving out the releaseDate: { $gte: new Date(dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')) } gives me the record. Tried it again just before writing this.

Comment: In that case I'm stumped. Code looks fine, data looks fine. For further debugging, I recommend flipping your query to `$lte`, then try copying the same query from your Mongoose-debug log to Robo3t and executing it there.